# How to recover data when Lumia phone shows "Error: unable to find a bootable option. Press any key to shutdown."

Tags: lumia-520

How to recover data when Lumia phone shows "Error: unable to find a bootable option. Press any key to shutdown."

Mine is Nokia Lumia 520, updated to Windows 8.1

I can try 'Windows Device Recovery Tool' to download and install new ROM+OS, but as per Microsoft website, the existing data will be deleted.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA142987

Please let me know if any solution is present to retrieve the data especially photos.

Is it ROM problem or OS problem? if ROM, then is it possible to update only ROM.

I tried connecting to laptop thru USB, but it is not shown as logical drive which could have been helpful.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I'd say your data probably already isn't recoverable. Were you syncing your pictures to OneDrive?

Comment: No. I have not enabled cloud storage

Comment: Were you using a micro SD card?